# How do I call the name of a user when they belong to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have two models, Chasing and User, a chasing belongs_to :user and a user has_many :chasings.

I created a migration for linking the two models together:

```
class AddUsersToChasings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :chasings, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

I have a controller for creating new users which I then want to be able to assign to chasings. I currently have this code in my chasings form for selecting the user:

```
<%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(User.all.map {|c| [c.name, c.id]}), { :include_blank => "Please select user"}, {:class => "form-control"} %>
```

This seems to do the trick, after calling Chasing.first in rails console I can see the chasing now has user_id relevant to the user I picked. I can also run Chasing.first.user.name to give me the name of the user who is associated with the chasing. I'm wanting to show this name in my index view, the code I currently have for this is:

ChasingsController:

```
def index
  @chasing = Chasing.all
end
```

Index view:

```
<% @chasing.each do |chasing| %>
  <%= chasing.user %>
<% end %>
```

This shows a random string (seems to change every time I update a chasing -     `#<User:0xf5b0ba8>` for example). when I change this to chasing.user.name I get *'undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass'*.

Is there a way I can call the name for my view?

EDIT:

As per NickM's comment below I had chasings without users assigned to them causing active record to throw the error.

Comment: Looks like you have some `Chasing` objects in your database without `user_id`s. You can test by doing `<%= chasing.user.name if chasing.user %>`

Comment: Ah, well spotted, added users to the rest of the chasings and I can now call chasing.user.name. I'll edit out the bit about pre-populating the user in to another question since it isn't really related, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have some `Chasing` objects in your database without user_ids. You can test by doing `<%= chasing.user.name if chasing.user %>`